# Make Linq.Expression suitable for where predicate?

Tags: linq

The new WCF Data Services toolkit allows you to obtain a parameter, which contains a property called FilterExpression of type System.Linq.Expressions.Expression. This property contains all the filters provided in the query-string parsed as an expression tree.  This can be useful to improve performance by carrying out the filter server side.

However, you cannot just pass the filter expression to a where clause. Assuming the filter expression is an Expression type, is there an easy way to make use of it in a server side linq to sql query?

This doesn't work:   `var query.Where(filterexpression).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is anything that can be `Expression< Func<TEntityType, bool> >` for any  Queryable of type `IQueryab<TEntityType>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if `query` is of type `IQueryable<T>`, you can pass in an `Expression`.  If you're using Linq to SQL, you should have access to `IQueryable<T>` objects.